# unable to use skip-test as a custom command in Cypress

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

I installed the module @cypress/skip-test and want to use it as a command. The suggestion is to add `require('@cypress/skip-test/support')` in the support/index.js file. So when I do that, I am still not able to use it as a custom command. (my file by the way is a typescript file - index.ts). Is there anything else that is needed in order to use it as a cypress custom command?

I get this error when using `cy.skipOn(true);`:

> TS2339: Property 'skipOn' does not exist on type 'cy & CyEventEmitter'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I think the path is wrong. The `cypress-skip-test` library is independent of the `@cypress` repository,

After install, if you look under `/node_modules/@cypress` there is no `/skip-test` sub-folder but there is a `/node_modules/cypress-skip-test` folder.

So if I switch the paths, I get a working test

```js
// import '@cypress/skip-test/support'
import 'cypress-skip-test/support'
```

Secondly, for the typescript error - they provide a `index.d.ts` type definition which you should add in `tsconfig.json`

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
  },
  "types": ["cypress"],
  "include": [
    "../../node_modules/cypress",
    "cypress/**/*.ts",
    "node_modules/cypress/types/index.d.ts",
    "node_modules/cypress-skip-test/index.d.ts",   // this line adds skip-test
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining that. I got it working with your suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

The release notes for the library [cypress-skip-test](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-skip-test) need updating.

If you are running a version of Cypress v10 or above, the correct file is `/cypress/support/e2e.ts`.

Also the convention for typescript is to use `import`, but you may find `require()` still works.

```js
// cypress/support/e2e.ts

import '@cypress/skip-test/support'
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and still was unable to use it as a cypress command.